# Cannot use the associated type of a trait with uninferred generic parameters?

Tags: rust

This example is from rust's [error-index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0212), whose explanation I still can't understand why this is the case

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    pub trait Foo<T> {
        type A;

        fn get(&self, t: T) -> Self::A;
    }

    fn foo2<I: for<'x> Foo<&'x isize>>(field: I::A) {} // error!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`I` does not implement `Foo` once in `foo2()`. It implements it *multiple times*, once for each lifetime of `'x`.

Because of that, there is also not a single value for `<I as Foo>::A`. There are multiple, one for each instantiation of `'x`.

When you want to specify `I::A`, you need to tell the compiler which `I::A` - that is, which lifetime to bind `'x` with.

Comment: I still don't understand something, can you explain it in detail?

Comment: @masion What do you don't understand?

Comment: I don't quite understand the first sentence（I does not implement Foo once in foo2(). ...）

Comment: @masion Yes, but you have a `where` clause, so there is an implementation in scope.

Comment: How should I understand the I in the foo2 function and what does it mean

Comment: @masion It's a generic parameter. Please read https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html.

Comment: I stands for for<'x> Foo<&'x isize>, and my current understanding I first needs to implement the Foo trait, and then perform a series of operations with a late binding. Is there a problem with this understanding, or what should a better understanding look like?

Comment: `I` is not an abbreviation for anything. It's a variable. The `for<'x> Foo<&'x isize>` is a *constraint* on that variable (and a rather complex constraint, at that). The two are not substitutable for each other.